# Take a screen shot of a specif area and save as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I want to make a program taking a cropped screenshot (like Windows+Shift+s) and save it as **variable**, not as a file.

1. How do I **Programmatically** open this win+shift+s window?
2. How to directly get the output **without saving this as a picture**?

I'm using **python**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to:

1. trigger the `Print screen` key (any keyboard library should allow it)
2. retrieve the data from the clipboard (you will maybe forced to save it as a temporary file and then read from it)
3. then parse the data it will be it will png format.